# Admob sdk request specific language

Tags: android, admob

Is there a way to request a specific language for an ad, overriding the default system language?

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.doubleclick_ad);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Was thinking something on AdRequest, but there is nothing obviously available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin, there is nothing that you can do. But Admob can and most certainly does interrogate the device to find out details like the locale and can and probably does utilize that.

Comment: Bummer.  Thanks for the reply, though.